# How many times does Angular 2 render a single page before showing it?

Tags: html, angular, rendering, angular2-template, console.log

I'm using Angular 2 for my project. I have a simple div in my template which calls a function in my .ts file that outputs a simple text like this:

```
<div>{{ test() }}</div>

test(): void {
    console.log("Test text");
}
```

When I load a page I get the same output many times like this:

```
Test text
Test text
Test text
Test text
Test text
```

Does that mean that Angular 2 renders the template many times before it actually shows it and consequently calls function every time?

Comment: It means that it triggers change detection many times, read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular renders the `AppComponent` and it's child components exactly once, except when you add remove parts of the DOM, then these added parts will be rendered again.

What you experience is Angulars change detection which runs quite frequently. See also [Why event triggers ChangeDetection even if OnPush strategy is ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507503/why-event-triggers-changedetection-even-if-onpush-strategy-is-on/45507542?noredirect=1#comment77976553_45507542).

It is usually a bad idea to use functions in value bindings because such functions will be called every time Angular runs change detection.

Prefer to assign the value to a property and bind to this property instead.

```
<div>{{ testVal }}</div>

ngOnInit() {
  this.testVal = this.test();
}

private test(): string {
    console.log("Test text");
    return 'some string';
}
```

Comment: "What you experience is Angulars change detection which runs quite frequently.". The change detection cycle runs when the user triggers any event or after all callbacks of all setTimeout and setIntervals are executed in the current event loop. In dev mode the cycle is run twice to make sure the rendered result is consistent. None of these things happen on startup so it would make sense for the cycle to be run twice, not 4 times. I am downvoting you because you didn't really explain this, which is the core of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It renders multiple time since ChangeDetectionStrategy is always "Default" means it check always(multiple times) for UI update

ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
Use OnPush: OnPush means that the change detector's mode will be set to CheckOnce during hydration.

If you use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush then it will print only once

changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://plnkr.co/edit/lNXNsS?p=preview

```
    @Component({
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
        Check Console
          <h2>{{print()}}</h2>
        </div>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      name:string;
      constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
        console.log("Called Once");
      }
      
      print(): void {
        console.log("I am printing only one time");
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Nisdex Hope this answer helped you?

Comment: on click it would re-render though. Is there a way to not re-render at all once rendered?

Comment: @RohanFating Your plunker doesn't seem to work. It has a colon in app.ts where you'd expect a semicolon. I tried fixing it but it doesn't load anyways. It's stuck with "loading...".

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52154#issuecomment-1756757851

> As you've noted, when running in dev mode, templates are executed twice: once during regular change detection and again to check that no changes to the template bindings happened. So we can remove this double checking by calling `enableProdMode`. The second change detection happens here because of `ZoneJS`. There are several Promises that resolve during bootstrapping which cause the zone to become "unstable" and then stable again, triggering a second change detection.
>
> Here's the example with no ZoneJS and prod mode showing only one execution of the binding: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dw5f16?file=src%2Fmain.ts

You usually get 2 change detection cycles in development, but on startup it's 4 because of ZoneJS and the promises that resolve during bootstrapping.