# Why event triggers ChangeDetection even if OnPush strategy is ON?

Tags: angular

When we use **Default Strategy** this guys could trigger Change Detection(of course except input params):

- user events
- timers
- ajax response

BUT. When you switch to **OnPush Strategy** it's trigger only by **events** and does not work for timers and http.

So the questions is why it does not work for times and https or why it works for events.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`OnPush` is defined this way.

It triggers change detection

- when a DOM event the component listens to was received
- when the `|async` pipe receives a new event
- when an `@Input()` was updated by change detection.
- when explicitly registering the component to be checked the next change detection turn using `ChangeDetectorRef::markForCheck`

`ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` triggers change detection for every async callback called within Angulars zone (every DOM even listened to within the Angular application, every Observable event or completed Promise, setTimeout, ...)

Comment: Considering the `DOM` event, does that include any `(event)` binding inside the template, or only `@HostListeners`?

Comment: Every event that has an event listener registered from within the Angular zone, that includes `xxx.addEventListener()`, `(domEvent)`, `@HostListener()`.

Comment: Yes yes, but if a component is set to `OnPush`, then I guess that if you have `xxx.addEventListener()` inside the logic of the component, the change detection won't be triggered, right?

Comment: `xxx.addEventListener()` won't run `markForCheck` https://plnkr.co/edit/k56NahyP8bdagVbjnOPl?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thanks again. I meant it causes change detection to run with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` but that's probably not what the comment was about. With `OnPush` it's only `(click)` and `@HostListener()`