# Angular 4 - html input element change event triggers @Input() setter with OnPush strategy

Tags: angular

**I have a simple component:**

```
@Component({
  // ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {

  private _items: string[];

  @Input()
  set items(items) {
    console.log('setter of items: ', items); // verify call
    this._items = items;
  }

  onChangeValue(event) {
    console.log('on change value', event);
  }
}
```

**It's template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of _items">
  {{item}}
</div>

<input type='text' (change)='onChangeValue($event)'>
```

**Question:**
Why the setter `@Input() set items(..)` is being called after the text has been changed in the `input` element and the `onChangeValue` function is called.

I thought Angular's change detection strategy `OnPush` will trigger the `@Input() set items(..)` function `if and only if` the parent component passes in a new reference of items to this component.

However, `@Input() set items(..)` is also triggered when the input text has changed.

**Why??**

Comment: Are there any bindings to the input?

Comment: There are indeed - and working.

Comment: A reproduction in http://stackblitz.com would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45507542/5490505):

> OnPush is defined this way.
>
> It triggers change detection
>
> 1. when a DOM event the component listens to was received
> 2. when the |async pipe receives a new event
> 3. when an @Input() was updated by change detection.
> 4. when explicitly registering the component to be checked the next change detection turn using ChangeDetectorRef::markForCheck
>
> ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default triggers change detection for every
>   async callback called within Angulars zone (every DOM even listened to
>   within the Angular application, every Observable event or completed
>   Promise, setTimeout, ...)

So, in your case, change detection is being triggered by a DOM event the component listens to.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the helpful reply. Is there any way change detection only fires on (3) ?

Comment: @Dachstein So far as I'm aware, no. There are only [two possible change detection values](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy). `Default` or `OnPush`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains my question well!