# Why is ChangeDetection triggered on Mat-Table header hover (despite using OnPush)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-changedetection

I'm having performance problems with a `mat-table` triggering change detections despite using `OnPush`.

Here is a working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjouzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

When hovering the header cells, you will see the random number change.

Why would hovering on the table header trigger a change detection on the parent components ?

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be internal to Angular Material, and is triggered on the header arrow animation (start and finish).

Upon further inspection in the source code, it seems that animation hooks are used for the sorting header :

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sort/sort-header.html#L33

This indeed triggers a change detection on the element, which is bubbled up to the parent component, and all of its parents.

You can try detaching the sorter view to disable change detection, but by doing so, you will also loose the sort arrow animation (assuming it works to detach it).

Comment: Why would the CD bubble up despite parent n+2 being OnPush ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think you're thinking that `OnPush` disables change detection, which it doesn't.  `OnPush` trill triggers change detection when a template bound variable has its reference changed.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler this is by design, the change detection gets bubbled. Here is a simple example to demonstrate it (open the console, click on the title) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byh7zf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: @MikeS isn't the purpose of OnPush to isolate parents from their children ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no, the purpose of `OnPush` is to reduce the "magical" detection Angular uses, to improve performances

Comment: Yes @temp_user, but check the cases when CD is triggered : Input() change, event handler or the `async` pipe (which triggers detectChanges).

Comment: [This](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/) might be a good read about `OnPush` change detection. As far as my understanding goes, it is used to prevent "eager" change detection as it's the case with `Default` change detection.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler the input is not changed from the parent, but directly from the child.  But my point was to explain that a parent needs to be aware of changes made in the child to adapt to it. There's probably a way to disable that, but hnoestly in your case, I think you should be fine. But you definitely seem to have misunderstood the goal of `OnPush`, so be sure to look more into it !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler didn't mean to offend you, sorry if it did !

Comment: You should try using [detach](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach). Also, as far as I know, every mat component has a private cdr. You could also try to get a reference of the table using a view child and triggering the detach from the mat component it self once rendered.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi tried it, detaching any component that comes after the one having the table, completely disables any change detection in the components, including animations of the sort arrows.

Comment: That's the negative part of detaching a view from the inner render tree. It's all or nothing. In case you'll use a detach you will have to trigger its update whenever is needed - IE at the start and end of the arrow's animation.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi true, I'd say it's too much hassle but maybe this is what he needs !

Comment: @temp_user pardon my rudeness. I was 100% expecting DOM event would trigger on CD parents yet, I came to the conclusion that I was wrong. Cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507503/why-event-triggers-changedetection-even-if-onpush-strategy-is-on

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no issue on my side, glad you did the research anyway !