# Why the angular binding run 4 times?

Tags: angular, binding

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  str = () => {
    console.log('123123');
  };
}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<p>{{str()}}</p>
```

[image: console.log]

when I reload the browser and check the log. Angular relog 4 times. If you know why this happened, please let me know.

link stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqjr2d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this question is similar to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45500701/how-many-times-does-angular-2-render-a-single-page-before-showing-it)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the component tree will be re-check/rendered every couple of seconds.
This behavior is due to how Angular evaluates the DOM (take a look at [Angular lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#sequence-and-frequency-of-all-lifecycle-events)).

A way to improve it, is using [`ChangeDectionStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) in the `Component` Object with the `OnPush` option, as it will be only checked once and when is explicitly invoked.

[This article](https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7) may help you as well=)

Comment: The change detection cycle is not just run "every couple of seconds" as you say, but rather when either any event is triggered by the user (a click anywhere or typing on a text field), or after all callbacks of all setTimeouts and setIntervals are executed in the current event loop.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are calling a method in template, and angular doesn't know what that method could return, so it have to call it during every change detection cycle. In dev mode angular perform every change detection twice, plus when you load a component it have to render template then check it for changes.

load template + check for whether template is correct = 2 cycles.

dev mode each cycle twice. so it becomes 2x2 = 4.

Comment: You are wrong. In dev mode every change detection cycle is run twice: One when the template is being loaded and another afterwards to make sure the changes are consistent. You say "template + check for whether template is correct = 2 cycles". But then you proceed to say "dev mode each cycle twice. so it becomes 2x2 = 4.". In dev mode each cycle is run twice, one of which is to load the template and the other to check the template is correct. Your last sentence doesn't make sense because the second time the cycle is run is already included in your previous sentence but you include it again.

Comment: @Adrian its like load template( twice) + check for whether template is correct (twice) due to dev mode. Just writing that Answer is wrong doesn't make sense.  Please Add the correct one if you are so sure.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52154#issuecomment-1756757851 "The second change detection happens here because of ZoneJS. There are several Promises that resolve during bootstrapping which cause the zone to become unstable and then stable again, triggering a second change detection."

Comment: @Adrian :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868896/10982972. Thats why its helpful to call enableProdMode to disable this double check.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question. A change detection cycle is run, for instance, when you click on a button with an event. When you do that you will see that in development you get 2 change detection cycles when you press the button and when in prod it's just one. This demonstrates that in dev change detection cycles run twice as often, but that doesn't answer why on startup it is 4 times in dev and 2 times in prod instead of just 2 in dev and one in prod as expected. Disabling prod only serves to demonstrates that it runs twice instead of just once on startup, not to explain why.